# Expanding a data frame to a square data frame from a sequence

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
           001        002        003        004         005        006       007        008        009       010
001 2970.91790  529.95796  144.67649  209.56510   151.90523   35.22495  53.70285   35.58293  259.27181  29.67257
002  524.03976 2131.87529  610.25863  589.38299   162.34014   23.34101 124.19162   40.71918  197.76410  28.05098
003  145.74773  626.36473 3622.55336  389.35216   200.95058   25.71455 415.04428   51.47006  154.43581  44.88253
004  212.11149  580.99852  392.15305 1210.81160   130.20255   31.94426  70.47914   34.11284  122.72711  18.06155
005  151.05275  144.80547  213.62125  137.71509 32883.70397   44.14327 101.63690  424.35085         NA 587.05350
006   32.74308   20.64950   25.00262   33.10395    49.95159 1693.07820  10.50745   13.96789   34.73152   2.24825
007   55.18095  130.55123  413.97881   70.52564   112.58922   10.38378 822.24467   23.83408  136.28197  21.90567
008   33.34998   37.40042   52.01565   35.23724   412.20117   13.00695  22.65692 5151.59610   41.96738 707.58984
009         NA         NA  159.00873         NA   168.67940   34.67111        NA         NA 3832.31150  41.39212
014  106.49849  131.96954         NA         NA  3812.34763         NA        NA         NA         NA        NA
```

I want to expand the data frame rows and columns out to a sequence of 001:020. I know the `complete` function from the `tidyr` might help here but I can’t figure out how to expand the columns and rows. The expected output would be a square data frame with rownames going from 1 – 20 and column names going from 1 – 20 with the expanded data filled in as NA.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(`001` = c(2970.91790096752, 524.039762637751, 
145.747730938099, 212.111490876205, 151.052745498845, 32.7430778562688, 
55.1809455425078, 33.3499843838982, NA, 106.498489681513), `002` = c(529.957956290217, 
2131.87529253411, 626.364731060584, 580.998520639855, 144.805467234981, 
20.649498701031, 130.551232599674, 37.4004203706326, NA, 131.969541987316
), `003` = c(144.676492202146, 610.258631567603, 3622.55336478711, 
392.153054928216, 213.621245023278, 25.0026194605605, 413.978813410475, 
52.0156507608533, 159.008729542202, NA), `004` = c(209.565103120956, 
589.382985788104, 389.352159209158, 1210.81159668811, 137.715094668041, 
33.1039531263303, 70.5256438615366, 35.2372382360528, NA, NA), 
    `005` = c(151.905227363017, 162.34014250043, 200.950579688627, 
    130.202545532454, 32883.7039682134, 49.9515924103773, 112.589224714273, 
    412.201174834326, 168.679397466466, 3812.34763240316), `006` = c(35.2249505160079, 
    23.3410057877637, 25.7145524356586, 31.9442649026236, 44.1432667825126, 
    1693.07819561552, 10.3837843257454, 13.0069457755982, 34.671111815481, 
    NA), `007` = c(53.7028489805572, 124.191615344556, 415.044278901963, 
    70.4791355665571, 101.636899796955, 10.507451141674, 822.24466846814, 
    22.6569185198606, NA, NA), `008` = c(35.5829327227688, 40.7191787171941, 
    51.4700566090128, 34.1128383722329, 424.350848669844, 13.967891533784, 
    23.8340843203951, 5151.59609542286, NA, NA), `009` = c(259.271808139472, 
    197.764102483701, 154.435812224047, 122.727113464259, NA, 
    34.7315201840341, 136.281970511925, 41.9673755498124, 3832.31150179321, 
    NA), `010` = c(29.6725705207802, 28.0509751055438, 44.8825283474144, 
    18.0615538496469, 587.053499875924, 2.2482503507454, 21.9056661956918, 
    707.589840063553, 41.3921239197016, NA)), row.names = c("001", 
"002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "014"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

a data.table approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data, keep.rownames = TRUE)
ans <- CJ(sprintf("%03d", 1:20), sprintf("%03d", 1:20))[melt(data, id.vars = "rn"), 
                                                        value := i.value,
                                                        on = .(V1 = rn, V2 = variable)]
dcast(ans, V1 ~ V2, value.var = "value")
```

Comment: How can I `map` this over multiple lists of data frame?

Comment: not sure without sample data, but try `lapply(mylist, function(x) { ... })` with the code in the answer on the `...`, replace `data` with `x`